# Fastest way to copy one array list to another

Tags: java, arraylist

I came across a question related to ArrayList of java in a company written test. My query is just a small part of the actual question.

Lets say we have the following function to copy one ArrayList to another:

```
void function(List<E> l)
{
    List<E> m = new ArrayList<E>(l);
}
```

The question basically asks to optimize this copy operation. The List may contain a million entries. I have tried the following approaches:

Collections.copy

System.Arraycopy

addAll

But all of these seem to be slower than the given method. I need a method that is faster than the given method or is it the best method that is available?

Comment: Nope, that's totally the best method available.

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableList(list) is faster, but may be unsuitable for the intend (which I find extremely poorly defined in the question).

Answer (score 5):

Well Firstly I think there is a benchmark error. `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` uses `Arrays.copyOf` which internally uses `System.arraycopy` (Source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)). Hence `System.arraycopy` or `addAll` cannot be slower than your mentioned code.

For the question, there cannot be a faster way (given you wish to not loose the type information, that might save clock cycles but very trivial) as the operation will have to be `O(n)`. And `System.arraycopy` is the fastest way out there given it uses native calls to copy them fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you get dirty, Unsafe will be slightly faster. However you have to get access to the underlying   Object array of the ArrayLists using reflection. Use this only if you are in a life-or-death situation regarding performance.

public native void copyMemory(java.lang.Object o, long l, java.lang.Object o1, long l1, long l2);

Comment: That shouldn't actually be any faster than `System.arraycopy()`, since it probably calls into very similar native code.

Comment: not necessary. Unsafe copy is an intrinsic in HotSpot and does no bounds check. However the difference will be minimal and only notable if copying many small sized arrays. Its probably not worth it however one could give the unsafe version a shot. The VM is not that predictable :-)